# copy form field values in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form with shipping and billing address related input fields, I have a checkbox called "Same as shipping". On clicking the checkbox the field values from shipping address should be copied to billing address field and also the billing address field should watch for the changes in the shipping address. The input fields are in a formgroup and the inputs have formControlName.

Below is my form group

```
    this.customerForm = fb.group({
          'id': [],
          'company_code': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
          'company_name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
          'is_important': false,
          'credit_term': [],
          'contacts': fb.array([
              this.initContacts(),
           ]),
          'shipping_addresses': fb.array([
              this.initShippingAddresses(),
           ]),
          'billing_addresses': fb.array([
              this.initBillingAddresses(),
           ])
        });

  initShippingAddresses() {
    return this.fb.group({
        'id': [''],
        'name': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'street_1': [],
        'street_2': [],
        'city': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'state': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'country': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'zip': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        'is_residential': []
    });
  }
```

Below is my function which is triggered when "Same as shipping" checkbox is clicked

```
  updateCheckedOptions(key, event) {
    if(event.target.checked){
    }
    else{
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 updateCheckedOptions(key, event) {
    if(event.target.checked){
      const shipping = this.customerForm.get('shipping_addresses');
      const billing = this.customerForm.get('billing_addresses');
      billing.setValue(shipping.value);
    }
    else{
    }
  }
```

#### Update

If you want to update both values you can listen for changes and update the form group as they happen:

```
      // billing.setValue(shipping.value);
      billing.valueChanges.subscribe(value => shipping.value = value);
```

You'll probably have to refactor your code somewhat, so you don't subscribe every time you check "same as shipping" option. Main point is to use `setValue` to update form controls and `valueChanges` to track changes.

Comment: It copies the values from shipping address to billing address, thanks for that. If the "same as shipping" is in checked state then the changes I make in the shipping address fields should reflect in the billing address automatically, its not happening now.

Comment: I updated the answer, but I would suggest to rethink what you're doing as it is not a good UX (; It's better to show/hide some fields than to display them twice (with potential errors, etc). You can reuse value when you submit form instead of duplicating values (and errors) on the go...